# Creating a DB for comment sections with multiple page tags

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm having a tough time choosing the correct database (SQL, NoSQL) for this use case even though it's so common.

This is the main record -

**Page**:
Contains a number of fields (which will probably change and updated in the future).
Connected to a list of tags (Which can contain up to 50 tags).
Connected to a comment section.

Page records will be queried by using the tags.

In general, the reads are more important (so writes could be more expensive) and the availability should be high.

The reason not to choose mongodb style DB is because of the comment section, There are no joins, so the comment section must be embedded in the page and the document size could grow too much.
Also MongoDB is less reliant on availability (using CAP) and availability is important to me.

The reason not to choose SQL is because the scheme of the Page could be updated and there is no fixed scheme.
Also because of the tags system - another relational table should be created and as I understood, it's bad for performance.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm asking for the best approach, using SQL or NoSQL for this use case

Comment: @GordonLinoff if the OP new more about performance, they wouldn't be asking questions on SO ;-) While I agree, it's borderline for SO, they are asking for NoSQL vs Relational advice not product opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) and you can have the best of both.

Postgres supports [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXINGhttps://) which allows indexing of jsonb data types so your search by tags can be executed pretty efficiently, or keep them as an array data type.

If you concerned about the comments embedding, then link off to another table and benefit from joins which are first-class citizens.

Given your use-case, you could have a Pages table with main, well known columns and a few foreign keys to Authors etc, tags as an array or jsonb column, some page attributes in jsonb and your comments in a separate Comments table with foreign key to Users and Pages.

Both Mongodb and Postgres and great choices.

PS, I have built far more on Mongodb than Postgres, but really impressed by Postgres after recent evaluation for a new project.

Comment: Thanks! So you advise to use the array for the tags which would be also indexed instead of creating another table.. What about the scaling? I heard that horizontal scaling for sql is painful

Comment: @Chev . . . The question should be closed, not answered.  It is asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not a software recommendation. I'm asking for the best approach, using SQL or NoSQL for this use case

Comment: @Drxxd, personally I would keep the tags embedded in the document and create an appropriate index - unless you foresee the need to have localized tags in the future, which is unlikely. Comments per page will be few and probably not searched, so they could be embedded but no reason you should not move to a sep table with a foreign key. In most nosql products you could batch queries together to get comments and page collection. Relational DB's are built to join so use them - just don't go crazy with the depth. Pic two products, model the architecture, bulk load and profile your use cases.

Comment: PS, had this [Guardian article on migrating from mongo](https://www.theguardian.com/info/2018/nov/30/bye-bye-mongo-hello-postgres) bookmarked which could be an interesting read for you.